# Is it possible to run a raid-1 on a 2 hard drive usb device?

Tags: raid, raid-1

I have an Icy Box ([https://www.amazon.de/IB-3620U3-Externes-Festplatten-Anschluss-Smart-Lüfter/dp/B00I4E2FYI](https://www.amazon.de/IB-3620U3-Externes-Festplatten-Anschluss-Smart-L%C3%BCfter/dp/B00I4E2FYI)), which I would like to run a raid 1 system on.

But I am curious whether that will actually work because the Icy Box is not having an integrated CPU.

What are your thoughts about that?
Will that work or not?

Comment: The specs say it supports SATA III, which is the best choice for RAID or any kind. USB drives for RAID will provide significantly sub-par performance, and are Not Recommended.

Comment: okay, that's good news since I don't really care all too much about speed but I m wondering whose right because @LawrenceC said that it isn't possible to run a raid on the linked device

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the way this USB device acts without:

- hacking the embedded controller;
- using any utilities provided by the manufacturer that might let you change how this is configured (I can't find any).

There are some USB devices like this where you can change the configuration to be RAID-0 or RAID-1 (I have an old Seagate external enclosure that is like this) but this doesn't look like one of them.

You would have to do any RAID in software with this device.